# Any way to pass `this` to another class without creating an infinite object?

Tags: javascript

So recently I was looking at another application and how it handled events and it seemed nice because all of the events were emitted from the main module instead of a nested one.

Also the below example uses the EventEmitter from Node.js but I didn't feel like I should tag it because this behavior is the same in the browser but this pattern below is similar to what I use quite often.

Here is a basic example:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const actor = require('./actor');

module.exports = class Movie {
    constructor() {
        this.actor = new Actor(this);
    }
}
```

And in another module you would have:

```
module.exports = class Actor {
    constructor(movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    hi() {
        this.movie.emit('some-event', someData);
    }
}
```

And this is nice because then in your main file you could do something like:

```
const Movie = require('./movie');

const movie = new Movie();
movie.on('some-event', (someData) => {});
```

This looked odd to me though so I tried it and it seems it just creates an infinite object because each time I open up the movie object I see actor and inside actor I see movie, and so on.

Is there a way to do this without creating an infinite object or does it not even matter performance wise since I have seen it used in production?

Note that the alternative way and the way I currently do this is to have the eventemitter on the Actor class and emit from there but then it becomes `movie.actor.on('some-event', (someData)  => {});`

Comment: The "infinite" object is actually just two objects that each contain references to one another. There's no performance problem.

Comment: @4castle Really, so it's no problem at all? It's weird to think about because what we can see is just a never ending object when expanding it but in memory it does no such thing?

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy Objects are not literally copied in memory here. They just store the reference of the other object in the memory.

Comment: @PrakashSharma Ah ok that makes sense. Do you guys recommend I close this question?

Answer (score 0):

You create this infinite loop by passing movie context to the actor. Change :

```
class Movie {
    constructor() {
        this.actor = new Actor(this);
    }
}
```

to this:

```
class Movie {
    constructor() {
        this.actor = new Actor();
    }
}
```